# What software can I use to draw this figure?

Tags: figure

Can anybody suggest me a simple software to draw a figure something like in the below link.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Visio](http://www2.buyoffice.microsoft.com/usa/product.aspx?country_id=US&culture=en-US&family=o14_visiopro&action=buy&WT.term=%2bfree%20%2bmicrosoft%20%2bvisio&WT.mc_id=pointitsem_OTB%20US_google_Visio%20-%20Trial&WT.medium=cpc&WT.campaign=Visio%20-%20Trial&WT.content=JeRw0IzT&WT.srch=1&WT.source=google&cshift_ck=c797cc87-a0ca-4f28-9741-94edbbb2ea4dcsJeRw0IzT) or  [SmartDraw](http://www.smartdraw.com/) or [this free online tool](http://www.gliffy.com/gliffy/#)

Comment: Thanks Diego!! The online tool was really good!!

Answer (score 0):

The [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) suite provides several tools to convert a simple, textual description into a graphical representation of a a graph or diagram. And it's free (as in freedom or beer) to boot.